# How to not re-render the whole list in Mithril

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I've used react for quite some time and wanted to try out Mithril.js.

Went through the documentation and the examples and liked what I saw, so I said I should get my hands dirty and start coding!

I have a smiple API call that receives a JSON data and then outputs `ul` list with all the items. I've integrated GSAP TweenMax for animations and what I'm trying to achieve is very simple - I fade everything in, on onload and then `onclick` I want to fade to fade an element out and remove it from DOM / data.

What seems to be happening is that the element is fading out, the whole `ul` list is being re-rendered and that element remains in the DOM with 0 opacity:

```
var Item = {
    list: function() {
        return m.request({method: 'GET', url: '/api/items'});
    }
}

var dm = {
    controller: function(data) {                
        var items = Item.list();
        return {
            items: items,
            remove: function(item) {                
                items().data.splice(items().data.indexOf(item), 1);
            }
        }
    },

    view: function(ctrl) {      
        return m('ul', [
            ctrl.items().data.map(function(item, id){
                return m('li',{
                    key: id,
                    config: fadesIn,
                    onclick: fadeOut(ctrl.remove.bind(this, item))
                }, item.title);
            })
        ]);
    }
}

var fadesIn = function(element){
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.from(element, .5, {opacity: 0});
}

var fadeOut = function(callback) {
    return function(e) {
        m.redraw.strategy('none');
        TweenMax.to(e.target, .5, {opacity: 0, onComplete: function() {
            m.startComputation();           
            callback();         
            m.endComputation();
        }});
    }
}

m.mount(document.getElementById('test'), dm);
```

I'm very new.. started reading up just yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting animation libraries to work with Mithril can be tricky. When libraries manipulate DOM state the synchronization with Mithril state can be broken.

Fortunately that wasn't the case: What you're missing is the `isInitialized` parameter for the config function, which is false only on the first call. Testing for that makes the fade-in only happen once:

```
var fadesIn = function(element, isInit){
    if(isInit) return;
    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.from(element, .5, {opacity: 0});
}
```

In this simple example the redrawing can also be simplified, I've made a fiddle with a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ciscoheat/dkyc0ryc/

Since there are no DOM manipulations a call to `m.redraw` is enough to remove the div from DOM, but you're probably right in using `start/endComputation` when things get more complex. I would even move `m.startComputation` above the `TweenMax.to` call to make it extra safe, but if many other things are happening at the same time, that may block other redraws. You have to find a balance. :)

The call to `m.redraw.strategy` isn't needed in any case, I think. It's mostly used when you want nothing at all to happen (synchronously as well), but an async animation is starting so it won't have any effect.

**Edit:** Found another problem, the `key` cannot be set to the index of the map function, then it will change when an item is removed, messing up the redraw. I've updated the fiddle to use `item.title` as key instead.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well and fixed on my end. Thanks for such explanation! I wish there was a proper video tutorial / course on how to use Mithril in real world scenarios. The Todo list is just never enough to get a proper idea of how the framework works... :( I'll have to switch back to React, because I just couldn't get any farther than simple Todo-like apps with Mithril.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm using Haxe (http://haxe.org) for web development, using OOP with MVC instead of the hybrid js style simplifies things quite a lot I must say. More advanced tutorials moves quickly into system architecture, which takes much to write about. Mithril keeps it simple and possible to focus on the architecture, React complicates things and moves things more into structure and abstractions. Oh well, many random thoughts... Wish I had time to write some about it. Maybe later. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I liked about Mithril, it's so flexible, but I just can't figure out how I would use it for the real world, daily projects. I wish there was a video of someone building an app with Mithril.

Comment: I understand, it's not simple. The two things that helped me most in my deep dives into MVC (including talking to the author) is to make the View into an object, and that any M,V and C combination can be played by the same object. I just commented about it here: http://adrianperez.org/avoid-polluting-mvc-an-opinionated-rubyist-view/#comment-2160997524 if you want to know more about it, feel free to drop me a mail.